# how to use bluecove-emu

Tags: java, bluecove

I am developing a simple java app that should make use of bluetooth to send data. The problem is when compiled I get an exception for BluetoothStack not detected because I don't have a bluetooth device. I heard bluecove the jsr 82 implementation am using supports bluetooth device simulation with bluecove-emu. I have no idea how to use it to simulate a bluetooth device  and it would help if you could provide me with examples or links to instructions even just give me the instructions right here if you have the time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer from people if you're more specific. The BlueCove website has examples and documentation...so what did you try? What didn't work and why didn't it work? Or what don't you understand, what is missing?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am working with the examples. I get the exception because I don't have a bluetooth device. What I don't understand is how to simulate a bluetooth device using bluecove.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the instructions are [here](http://bluecove.org/bluecove-emu/) I had come across this page a while back but I didn't notice the **USAGE** section. Now that I notice it am having a hard time understanding what am supposed to do. Can anyone help me understand what these instructions mean.

Start local bluetooth air simulator server

```
java -cp bluecove-2.1.0.jar;bluecove-emu-2.1.0.jar com.intel.bluetooth.emu.EmuServer
```

Start jsr-82 application that connects to air simulator server

```
java -Dbluecove.stack=emulator -cp bluecove-2.1.0.jar;bluecove-emu-2.1.0.jar;yourApp.jar org.your.app.Main
```

Start MIDP jsr-82 application that connects to air simulator server

```
java -Dbluecove.stack=emulator -cp microemulator.jar;bluecove-2.1.0.jar;bluecove-emu-2.1.0.jar org.microemu.app.Main btApp.jad
```